# Python url_for redirects to HTTP not HTTPS

Tags: python, nginx, flask, ssl, https

so I have Flask application and use url_for for the link

```
redirect_uri=url_for("auth_bp.login", _external=True)
```

My application is running in AWS EBS and has SSL certificate installed, so this should be redirecting to HTTPS but it does to HTTP

I have added

```
PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME = os.environ.get('PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME', 'https')
```

but it didn't help

I have also tried

```
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1, x_host=1)
```

but this didn't help either

Any ideas?